# Does google workspace marketplace give any kind of notification of installation?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

When someone installs my application to their google workspace, does google send any kind of notification to my infrastructure - say via webhook?

Or am I responsible for the onboarding/first-run experience on my own, either via polling or upon the first time a user visits my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Google doesn't notify you directly anywhere. To do this you have to use the [`licenseNotification.list`](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification/list) API. With this you can get a list of installs/uninstalls of your app along with the user emails. A sample response would look like this:

```js
    {
      "kind": "appsmarket#licenseNotification",
      "id": <some-notification-id>,
      "applicationId": <your-app-id>,
      "customerId": "email@example.com",
      "timestamp": <unix-timestamp>,
      "provisions": [
        {
          "kind": "appsmarket#provisionNotification",
          "editionId": "default_edition",
          "seatCount": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
```

As you can see, it contains the email of the user and whether or not it was provisioned. It also returns a `nextPageToken` with the last notification `id`, so you can store it and send it in your next request as `startToken` and get results after the last notification you got. With this in mind, you could build some kind of [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) service to poll the API periodically and notify your app when you get new provisioned users.

##### Reference:

- [licenseNotification.list](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification/list)

Comment: can you provide structure of example endpoint with credentials? I'm not able to  authenticate this GET with any of my auth0 or apikey set in Credentials.